# How do I limit the number of selected choices in a multi-select list using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have *n* number of choices in a select box. After the user selects one or more choices in the select box and submits the form, I need to check that the user hasn't selected more than four choices.

I tried the following:

```
function howMany() {
     var selObj = document.getElementsByName('xid[]');

     var totalChecked = 0;

     for (i = 0; i < selObj.options.length; i++) {
         if (selObj.options[i].selected) {
             totalChecked++;
         }
     }
     if (totalChecked > 4) {
        alert("You can't check more than 4 options");
        return false;
     }
     return true;
}
```

Comment: Multiple selects are a fairly nasty UI that lots of users have difficulty with. I suggest changing to a checkbox group instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if its a simple javascript.. here  you go.

```
<pre>
<html>
    <script>
        function howMany() {
                 var selObj = document.getElementById('paramid[]');
                 var totalChecked = 0;
                 for (i = 0; i < selObj.options.length; i++) {
                     if (selObj.options[i].selected) {
                         totalChecked++;
                     }
                 }
                 alert( totalChecked );
                 if (totalChecked > 4) {
                    alert("You can't check more than 4 options");
                    return false;
                 }
                 return true;
       }
        function testSubmit() {
            return howMany();
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <form action="http://google.com">
            <select name="paramid[]" id="paramid[]" multiple>
                <option>TEST1</option
                <option>TEST2</option
                <option>TEST3</option
                <option>TEST4</option
                <option>TEST5</option
                <option>TEST6</option
                <option>TEST7</option
            </select>
            <input type="submit" onclick="return testSubmit()" name="s" value=" How Many " id="s"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
</pre>
```

Comment: Your formatting is broken, and you probably should mention that this requires the HTML to be modified (you should also fix it so it doesn't require the HTML be modified so that it is invalid, [ and ] are not allowed in id attributes in HTML).

Answer (score 2):

The clue is in the name of the first DOM object you call: get**Elements**ByName

This returns a node list of all the elements with that name. You want to snip the first one off the list.

```
     var selObj = document.getElementsByName('paramid[]')[0];
```

Better yet, rather than searching through the entire document:

```
     var selObj = myForm.elements['paramid[]']
```

… where `myForm` is a reference to the form (which you could get from `this` if you used this function as a submit event handler).