# Android: Limit the number of choices multiple choice list view

Tags: android

In my app I have a multiple choice list view (simple_list_item_multiple_choice) and I want to limit the user to a 3 choices. Afterwards - if he chooses another option from the list - is not to be marked.

I thought do it with a counter (until three), but I dont know how to limit the fourth choice so it did not will be marked.

this is my code sketch:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) { } 
    });
```

how can I prevent the user di his 4-th choice?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Each time when you try to check new position, you have to loop through all elements in the list and check if they are checked. If the number of checked elements equals maximum number of checked elements, then you don't check pressed position. I think there is no other way to do it. Check the multipleChoiceView documentation. I think that this solution is the most appropriate here.

Here you have some example but it is in JavaScript:
[How do I limit the number of selected choices in a multi-select list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153482/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-selected-choices-in-a-multi-select-list-using-javas)

You can also disable other checkBoxes:
https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16659/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-options-a-user-may-choose-in-a-list

Also some code here:
[how to limit checkbox selection in listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149379/how-to-limit-checkbox-selection-in-listview)

Please next time do some research before asking the question.

Comment: listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
       int arg2, long arg3) {
      

     }
    });

Comment: I was looking for an answer for two hours but could not find an answer.

Thanks for the links but still I did not understand how I connect it to the list that is me.

I can not prevent the user to click on a row in the list, and if he clicks - I can not prevent the line be checked.

Comment: Inside onClick, you can use this in a loop and count how many of them is checked, listView.isItemChecked(i) // i is the position of the view. Then if you detect that too many of them was checked, you just uncheck listView.getItem(arg2).setChecked(false) ;

Comment: my list have "getItemAtPosition" and I havent "setChecked" option.